# Creating Database schema from application model or not?

Tags: database, model-view-controller, orm, model

Generally, I have a question about ORM(s), and the best way for managing enterprise/small applications' database schema and model (Actually, to keep application model and database schema sync always)

Is this a good way **to create database schema from application models** or **first creating database schema and then, create application model from it**? Which one is better?

**Note:** I see this principle in Django ORM, it has a tool which creates/syncs application database schema from application models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually start with a logical model (i.e. model the problem domain), and go from there.

In the dynamic scripting languages, the practice seems to be to create the classes and then let whatever database migration tool create the schema for you.

In Java/Hibernate, the shops I've been on have been too paranoid for that, so we created the DDL independently from the classes. The classes and ORM mappings then refer to an existing schema.

Comment: So don't you have any problem with that? I mean with it's maintainability?

Comment: The hard part of the dynamic scripting + migrations is that stuff would just kind of appear in the database, so the schema had a tendency to get messy. The problem on the Java+DDL approach was that if you wanted a new column or table, you had to write new DDL and arrange to run the script. So it kind of depends on how much fine-grained control you want over the schema & where you want to spend your time. But either way seemed reasonable for the projects I was on.